# Anaconda installation

Tags: python, anaconda

Which anaconda version should i install for ubuntu18.04 for python3.6?
Anaconda version for python3.7 is already available. Can it work for python 3.6? If not then which version is appropriate for python 3.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda 3.7 works with python 3.6, so it is recommended that you install the latest Anaconda with the latest python.